# Prove $A+ \emptyset = A, A+A = \emptyset$, and $A +A' = U$ using the definition of $A+B$

Tags: logic, proof-verification

I need to know if I'm on the right track on this

Let $A$ and $B$ be sets. Define the symmetric difference of $A$ and $B$, written $A+B$, by $A+B=(A \cup B) \backslash (A \cap B)$.

Prove the following statements.

a. $A+ \emptyset = A$, $A+A = \emptyset$, and $A +A' = U$

Part 1a.

$A+ \emptyset = A$

We need to define the symmetric difference of $A+ \emptyset$

$A+ \emptyset = (A \cup \emptyset) \backslash (A \cap \emptyset)$

Proposition: $\emptyset \cap A = \emptyset$ and $\emptyset \cup A = A$

However, the proposition will only work if we have $ \emptyset + A$

Proposition: $A \cap \emptyset = \emptyset$ and $A \cup \emptyset = A$

(ok I'm being honest here. Is it really safe to change the order of the letters in a proposition or do I have to switch the order of the whole problem?)

$A+ \emptyset = (A \cup \emptyset) \backslash (A \cap \emptyset)$

$A+ \emptyset = A \backslash \emptyset = A$

---

Part 2a.$A+A = \emptyset$

We need to define the symmetric difference of $A+ A$

($A \cup A) \backslash (A \cap A)$

Proposition: $A \cap A = A$ and $A \cup A = A$

Definition: Let A and A be sets. The complement of A relative to A, written $ A\backslash A$ is the set $A \backslash A = [x: x \in A \land x \notin A]$

$A \backslash A = \emptyset$

---

Part 3a.$A + A' = U$

$(A \cup A') \backslash (A \cap A')$

Propositions: $A \cup A' = U$ and $A \cap A' = \emptyset$

Definition: Let U and $\emptyset$ be sets. The complement of U relative to $\emptyset$, written $ U\backslash \emptyset$ is the set $U \backslash \emptyset = [x: x \in U \land x \notin \emptyset]$

$U \backslash \emptyset = U$

Comment: The order of the variables don't matter since intersection and union are commutative.  Thus, it's safe to switch $A$ and $\varnothing$

Comment: Other than that, I believe you did well with your proofs.

Comment: thanks for clarifying that. I know that in computational math, you have to follow the rules. It seems in pure math which is my first time doing you can change all sorts of stuff and I'm like omg is this legal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About :

> $A+ \emptyset = A$, $A+A = \emptyset$, and $A +A' = U$.

*a)* $A+ \emptyset$ is $(A \cup \emptyset) \backslash (A \cap \emptyset)$.

But you must remember that :

> $A \cup \emptyset = A \quad$ and that $\quad A \cap \emptyset = \emptyset$

so that :

> $A+ \emptyset$ is simply : $A \backslash \emptyset = A$.

This because, if you "throw away" the *empty set* form $A$, the result will be again $A$, whichever $A$ is (we need it again under *c)*).

*b)* $A+A$ is $(A \cup A) \backslash (A \cap A)$.

With the same reasoning, $A \cup A = A \cap A = A$, so that

> $A+A$ is $(A \backslash A) = \emptyset$.

*c)* $A+A' = (A \cup A') \backslash (A \cap A')$.

But $A \cup A' = U$ and $A \cap A' = \emptyset$.

Again, $U \backslash \emptyset = U$,

so that

> $A+A'=U$.

Comment: You did not base your arguments on axioms or some kind of definitions. When you say "This because, if you "throw away" the empty set form A, the result will be again A, whichever A is (we need it again under c))." it is a tautology, i.e. "something is like that because it is like that"

Comment: So you need to define at least what is empty set and what is A minus empty set rigorously.

Comment: @Theta30 - there was a long set of post about this kind of question by the same PO; we already discussed the fact that, using the rigorous definitions, $A \backslash B$ is simply $A \cap B'$, as you can see from the commets by the OP to your answer below.So my "reduction" of $A+ \emptyset$ to $A \backslash \emptyset$ take benefit of the previous result, omitting the passage : $A \backslash \emptyset = A \cap \emptyset' = A \cap U = A$.. Sorry for the sloppiness..