# Prove $A + (B+C) =B+(A+C) = C+ (A+B)$ using the definition of $A+B$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

Let $A$ and $B$ be sets. Define the symmetric difference of $A$ and $B$, written $A+B$, by $A+B=(A \cup B) \backslash (A \cap B)$.

Prove the following statement

$A + (B+C) = B+(A+C) = C+ (A+B)$

This is a mixture of associative law and commutative law.

Proof using associative law  which states that for all statements $P,Q$ and $R$.

$(P \land Q) \land R \leftrightarrow P \land (Q \land R)$ and $(P \lor Q) \lor R \leftrightarrow P \lor (Q \lor R)$

$A + (B+C) $

$A + (B \cup C) \backslash (B \cap C)$

$$
\begin{array}{c}
A+(B+C)\\
A+[(B \cup C) \setminus (B \cap C)]\\
(A \cup [(B \cup C) \setminus (B \cap C)]) \setminus (A \cap [(B \cup C) \setminus (B \cap C)])\\
\end{array}
$$

$B + (A + C )$

$B + (A \cup C) \backslash (A \cap C)$

$$
\begin{array}{c}
B+(A+C)\\
B+[(A \cup C) \setminus (A \cap C)]\\
(B \cup [(A \cup C) \setminus (A \cap C)]) \setminus (B \cap [(A \cup C) \setminus (A \cap C)])\\
\end{array}
$$

$C + (A+B) $

$C + (A \cup B) \backslash (A \cap B)$

$$
\begin{array}{c}
C+(A+B)\\
C+[(A \cup B) \setminus (A \cap B)]\\
(C \cup [(A \cup B) \setminus (A \cap B)]) \setminus (C \cap [(A \cup B) \setminus (A \cap B)])\\
\end{array}
$$

Proof for commutative law which claims that for all statements $P$ and $Q$

$P \land Q \leftrightarrow Q \land P$ and $P \lor Q \leftrightarrow Q \lor P$

$$
\begin{array}{c}
A+(B+C) = (B+C)+A \\
A + (B \cup C) \backslash (B \cap C) = (B \cup C) \backslash (B \cap C) + A\\
\end{array}
$$

$$
\begin{array}{c}
B+(A+C) = (A+C)+B \\
B + (A \cup C) \backslash (A \cap C) = (A \cup C) \backslash (A \cap C) + B\\
\end{array}
$$

$$
\begin{array}{c}
C+(A+B) = (A+B)+C \\
C + (A \cup B) \backslash (A \cap B) = (A \cup B) \backslash (A \cap B) + C\\
\end{array}
$$

I don't know what to do next...I'm not even sure if this is correct either.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps the simplest proof is via [Venn diagrams](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Venn_diagram).

[image]

The usual method of showing $A+(B+C) = B + (A+C)$ is to prove

1. $A+(B+C) \subseteq B + (A+C)$ and
2. $B + (A+C) \subseteq A+(B+C)$

Answer (score 2):

You arrived at :

$$B+(A+C)$$

$$B+[(A \cup C) \backslash (A \cap C)]$$

$$(B \cup [(A \cup C) \backslash (A \cap C)]) \backslash (B \cap [(A \cup C) \backslash (A \cap C)])$$

At this point, I will exploit the fact that $P \backslash Q$ "means" $x \in P$ **and** $x \notin Q$, i.e. $x \in P$ **and** $x \in Q'$.

I will try with the LHS part of the third formula above (left of $\backslash$). We have :

$$(B \cup [(A \cup C) \cap (A \cap C)'])$$

Now we play with De Morgan : $(A \cap C)'$ is $(A' \cup C')$. Replace and get :

$$(B \cup [(A \cup C) \cap (A' \cup C')])$$

Assuming that up to now is correct, we *distribute* and get :

$$[B \cup (A \cup C)] \cap [B \cup (A' \cup C')]$$

In this part, the $\cup$ ia *associative*, so that we can omit the inner parentheses :

$$[A \cup B \cup C] \cap [A' \cup B \cup C'] \quad --- (*)$$

Of course this is not enough to conclude; we must "unwind" the RHS of the $\backslash$ and see if it works (and it is much more difficult...).

We must work with :

$$(B \cap [(A \cup C) \backslash (A \cap C)])$$

In order to "join" it to the previous result we must used again the "trick" : $P \backslash Q$ is $P$ and not-$Q$, i.e. $P$ and $Q'$. So we start with $Q'$, i.e. :

$$(B \cap [(A \cup C) \cap (A \cap C)'])'$$

This is :

$$B' \cup [(A \cup C) \cap (A \cap C)']'$$

$$B' \cup [(A \cup C)' \cup (A \cap C)]$$

$$B' \cup [(A' \cap C') \cup (A \cap C)]$$

We work now with : $(A' \cap C') \cup (A \cap C)$ i.e. $[A' \cup (A \cap C)] \cap [C' \cup (A \cap C)]$ i.e $(A' \cup A) \cap (A' \cup C) \cap (C' \cup A) \cap (C' \cup C)$ i.e. $U \cap (A' \cup C) \cap (C' \cup A) \cap U$ and finally : $(A' \cup C) \cap (C' \cup A)$.

We have obtained :

$$B' \cup [(A' \cup C) \cap (C' \cup A)]$$

and finally :

$$[B' \cup (A' \cup C)] \cap [B' \cup (C' \cup A)] \quad --- (**)$$

Now we can "join" $(*)$ and $(**)$ with a "$\cap$" :

$$[A \cup B \cup C] \cap [A' \cup B \cup C'] \cap [B' \cup A' \cup C] \cap [B' \cup C' \cup A]$$

Now, we see "the pattern" : there is a "basic part" ($A \cup B \cup C$) from which we "cut away" (using $\cap$) three "slices".

The three slices are clearly invariant when we exchange the role of $A$ and $B$, and again when we exchange the role of $B$ and $C$, so (I suppose) it is enough to conclude that, starting with $A+(B+C)$ we will get the same result.

> Of course, in order to verify if the result is correct, we must check with the Venn diagrams in the answer by 01000100 above.

Answer (score 1):

The symmetric difference is often written $\Delta$.

Now note that $A\Delta B = (A\cup B)\setminus (A\cap B) = (A\setminus B)\cup (B\setminus A)$. In other words, being in $A\Delta B$ means being in exactly one of the two sets. So $x\in A\Delta B = (x\in A)\oplus (x\in B)$ where $\oplus$ is the XOR (or the addition modulo) $2$. That's where all the properties come from.

$$\begin{array}{l}
x\in A\Delta (B\Delta C)&\iff (x\in A)\oplus (x\in B\Delta C)\\
& \iff (x\in A) \oplus ((x\in B) \oplus (x\in C))\\
& \iff (x\in A) \oplus ((x\in C) \oplus (x\in B))\\
& \iff ((x\in A)\oplus (x\in C))\oplus (x\in B)\\
& \iff  (x\in B)\oplus((x\in A)\oplus (x\in C))\\
&\iff (x\in B)\oplus (x\in A\Delta C)\\
&\iff x\in B\Delta (A\Delta C)
\end{array}$$

That was the easy way, if you already knew properties of $\oplus$. But if you did not know that, you have two ways to go:

- Prove it using "truth tables" (in the case of sets, you just use cases). If $x\in A, x\in B, x \in C$, then $x\in A\Delta (B\Delta C)$ and $x\in B\Delta (A\Delta C)$. If $x\in A, x\in B, x \not\in C$, then $x\not\in A\Delta (B\Delta C)$ and $x\not\in B\Delta (A\Delta C)$... You do this for all the cases and the fact that you got the same result for both sets each time while checking all possibilities mean that both sets are equal.
- Get a gigantic expression of $A\Delta (B\Delta C)$ in conjunctive normal form ($(A_1\cap \dots \cap A_n)\cup \dots \cup (Z_1\cap \dots \cap Z_n)$). The commutativity of $\cup$ and the fact that the expression will be symmetrical in $A, B,C$ will help you prove what you want. If you do that, don't forget that $A\setminus B = A\cap B^c$ and use De Morgan's laws.

Comment: I have seen the XOR before. ...truth tables make take a while and apparently the answer for this problem is important because I need this and the results from a which I already proven easily to do the last problem which is .....................h. The statements $A+B = C, A + C = B,$ and $B +C = A$ are equivalent to each other. [Suggestion: Assume that $A+B=C$. Then "add" $(B+C)$ to both sides of the equation giving $(A+B)+(B+C) = C+(B+C)$. Then use parts (g) and (a) of this exercise.]

Comment: I've proven a here 
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/660230/prove-a-emptyset-a-aa-emptyset-and-a-a-u-using-the-definition